# Fast way to read from Datagridview to TextBox

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox, readfile

I have a trouble with reading from DataGridView and then export data to RichTextBox. I made a Program that read from 4 dataGridView and export data from each cells to the string in Textbox. For small files they work great, but when i have bigger files, my program freezes and doesn't show me the result. Is there any way to solve it?

my code i use to read cells in excel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    if (dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["ABC"].Value.ToString() != "")
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "ABC_ " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["ABC"].Value.ToString() 
        + " " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["DEF"].Value.ToString().Replace("\n", "") + ";";
    }
}
```

Of course it repeat this loop many times, coz i have many columns in datagridview

Comment: Did you try to store strings in memory until you finish loading, and then print them into the textbox?

Comment: @trippino: i think with my code above, it exports directly from datagridview to richtextbox or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes it does. Try to do it only when you finish loading (if it's the same for your intentions, of course)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```
richTextBox1.Text += "ABC_ " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["ABC"].Value.ToString() 
                + " " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["DEF"].Value.ToString().Replace("\n", "") + ";";
```

use:

```
richTextBox1.AppendText("ABC_ " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["ABC"].Value.ToString() 
                + " " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["DEF"].Value.ToString().Replace("\n", "") + ";");
```

It will work much faster.

In addition to this, you can use StringBuilder instead in which you can append text and then at the end, you can set that text to richTextBox1.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView4.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
     if (dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["ABC"].Value.ToString() != "")
     {

           sb.Append("ABC_ " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["ABC"].Value.ToString()
                    + " " + dataGridView4.Rows[i].Cells["DEF"].Value.ToString().Replace("\n", "") + ";");
     }
}
richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved but i have to explain something.

NikolaD's solution will be a lot faster because that code is not accessing complicated control (richTextBox) in big loop.

Any update of value of control on form is triggering some events. Slowest thing is screen update. If you run this 10000 times - it will take a lot time.

Writing (bufferring) data to normal variable, List or StringBuilder which is just stored in RAM (very fast memory) is a lot faster because it does not have to update display.

Don't try to update screen every few microseconds, its impossible :)

Comment: thanks, i will try with StringBuilder from NikolaD. Then i will post here if it's much faster

Comment: yes, it's much faster than i thought, specially for big files